# DI in android library project

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

I am working on the android library project, is it possible to use DI in an android library project ?

Koin for example need's an Application class

`class CustomLibrary : Application() {}`

but seems like something is wrong about using an Application class in a android library project

`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Is any one was in front of this kind of projects ?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to use DI in an android library project

Yes, you can have dependency injection, especially on conceptual level.

If you are working on a generic reusable library, then it's better not to use any particular DI tool since it makes the caller to depend on the same tooling.

To not depend on particular tooling, you can use regular constructor injection, for example:

- Declare interfaces in the library for whatever you need as dependencies
- Make library components to take those interfaces as constructor arguments
- Have the caller provide with implementations of those dependency interfaces

Whether you use a DI tool or not, providing the `Application` dependency belongs really to the app layer and not to a library. Wiring the top-level dependencies belongs to the top level.

Comment: So if i use koin to inject dependencies in my library, the app consuming it should use also koin ?

Comment: Yes, generally it's not the library's responsibility to provide an `Application`.